# How to solve espwifi.h library

Tags: esp8266

```
#include "WiFiEsp.h"

char ssid[] = "***";            // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "#";        // your network password
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     // the Wifi radio's statusb
char server[] = "apiv2.corona-live.com";

// Initialize the Ethernet client object
WiFiEspClient client;

void setup()
{
  // initialize serial for debugging
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // initialize serial for ESP module
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  // initialize ESP module
  WiFi.init(&Serial1);

  // check for the presence of the shield
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  }

  // you're connected now, so print out the data
  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  
  printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Starting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request
    client.println("GET /stats.json?timestamp=1634891368873 HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: apiv2.corona-live.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }
}

void loop()
{
  delay(500);
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them
   while(client.connected())
   {
      // There is a client connected. Is there anything to read?
      while(client.available() > 0)
      {
         char c = client.read();
         Serial.print(c);
      }
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println("Waiting for more data...");
      delay(100); // Have a bit of patience...
   }
  

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Disconnecting from server...");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore
    while (true);
  }
}


void printWifiStatus()
{
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("Signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

Result :

[WiFiEsp] Connecting to apiv2.corona-live.com
Connected to server
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
D[WiFiEsp] TIMEOUT: 720

https://apiv2.corona-live.com/stats.json?timestamp=1634891368873 Can I get JSON data from these sites? If possible, I would like to know why this error occurred.

(I use arduino mega 2560 + esp8266/esp01 module

Comment: use `connectSSL` and port 443. the site doesn't support insecure connection

Comment: Are you aware that there's almost 10kB of data and Mega has only 8kiB of RAM?

Comment: @gre_gor I hope they use a JSON streaming parser e.g. https://github.com/squix78/json-streaming-parser to avoid running out of RAM.